# jQuery keyboard shortcuts for website for focus goes to previous or next element using left n right keys

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am new in php and jQuery, can anyone please help me about keyboard shortcuts for website. means when we are on webpage and feeling registration form and we want to go to previous textbox using keyboard using left keypress..then how to focus goes on previous element..

m using below code but how to go to previous or next element...

```
 $(document).keydown(function(e){
      if (e.keyCode == 37) {
       // do something when left arrow is pressed
       return false;
       }
  });
```

Comment: PHP is a server-side scripting language. The code you have mentioned there looks like jQuery. Please change the title of your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, I think this keycode cheatsheet should help you => http://mikemurko.com/general/jquery-keycode-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use "window.location" for routing a page, I guess you know the previous and next page, then 
for the left arrow,

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
      if (e.keyCode == 37) {
       window.location = previousPageLink;
       return false;
       }
  });
```

for the right arrow,

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
          if (e.keyCode == 39) {
           window.location = nextPageLink;
           return false;
           }
      });
```

Comment: Vecihi Baltac , I dont want to go on next or previous page, I just want to go on next and previous element of form (like textbox, dropdown etc).so the Cursor focus goes to next or previous element on left n right arrow key press...

Comment: for example, your first element has tabindex = 0 and goes sequentially, you can use var index = $("#inputid").attr('tabindex'); $('input[tabindex=index]').focus();